# How to access parent or wrapper variables from an AS3 Worker Class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.6, flash-builder4.5

I am using Flash Builder 4.7 and have created a Worker Class. Below is the code:

```
package co.fuix.mobile.system.model
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.system.MessageChannel;
    import flash.system.Worker;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

    import mx.managers.SystemManager;

    public class InstantMessengerWorker extends Sprite
    {

        private var bm:MessageChannel;
        private var mb:MessageChannel;
        public function InstantMessengerWorker()
        {

            super();

            bm = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("BACK_TO_MAIN_CHANNEL");
            mb = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("MAIN_TO_BACK_CHANNEL");
            mb.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, onMainToBack);

        }

        protected function onMainToBack(event:Event):void
        {
            if(mb.messageAvailable){
                var s:SystemManager;
                trace('*'+mb.receive());
                trace('**'+mb.receive());
                trace('***'+mb.receive());
                trace(mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.myVariable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I reference a variable in the main mxml file. I know how to use message channels but I want to get that variable straight.

When I run the above code, this part

```
trace(mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.myVariable);
```

is giving me an error.

Any help will be regreatly appreciated

Comment: `"is giving me an error"` What error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access a variable from the main app like that.  They are running separately.  What you need to do is:

[Link to Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS2f73111e7a180bd0-5856a8af1390d64d08c-7ffe.html#WS2f73111e7a180bd0d047eb7139123f4689-8000)

Comment: Thank you @jason-reeves for your answer. At least I now know how it works. Then is it possible to share the FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication like so 
`worker.setSharedProperty("FlexGlobalsObject", mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication);` in the main SWF. Then in the worker I want to access the property as `flexGlobalsProperty = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("FlexGlobalsObject");`. Basically I want to share the FlexGlobals Object between the swf.

Comment: no that won't work.  only simple objects can be shared.  Basically you have two different flash players running and sending info back and forth either through a message channel or shared properties.  This is stateless and one can't see into the other for references... only pass messages back and forth (except ByteArray which is sharable).  The link I gave you is the ONLY way to handle communications to workers.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Now I understand. Its only that I started using Workers recently. ;)